# Getting long value for two equal date times yields different values

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want to use a date time as key in a MapReduce reduce-side join program. Table A has the value `2013-01-01 15:11:48` and table B has `1-1-2013 15:11 GMT`.

I'm parsing A as:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); //2013-01-01 15:11:48
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(df.parse(split[TaxiFields.PICKUP_DATETIME]));
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); //disconsidering the seconds
pickupDatetime.set(cal.getTime().getTime());
```

I'm parsing B as:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm zzz"); //1-1-2013 15:11 GMT,
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(df.parse(split[0]));
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
rainDate.set(cal.getTime().getTime());
```

However the first gives me a `1357063860000` as result, while the second gives me `1357053060000`.

What I'm missing? I try to set the time zones to default (`cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());`) but it did not work.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `setTimeZone` is changing the time by converting your datetime, rather than plainly setting it for an unknown timezone? Have you tried `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` for the first example?

Comment: Tried now, still returns the same value (1357053060000)...

Comment: Don't know that it helps, but the difference between the two long values corresponds to three hours' difference.

Comment: Note that you will not be able to get the same value for both, as one contains seconds while the other doesn't - so seconds default to 0.

Comment: I was setting the second in the one which contain seconds to zero already, thanks for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using two **equal** date times. You have:

1. `2013-01-01 15:11:48` in your local time zone (which is presumably not GMT)
2. `1-1-2013 15:11 GMT` which is in the GMT timezone

So these two dates differ by the number of hours between your timezone and GMT.

You can parse the first date as if it was in the GMT timezone:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); // 2013-01-01 15:11:48
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

If you do that, you'll get the same value for both date-times (`1357053060000`)